# Count changes made by users on a 3-tier table SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, group-by, sql-order-by

I am creating a SQL dataset for a report. I have 3-tier audit tables, (Account, AccountLevel, AccountDetail).

AccountLevel record is created automatically when new AccountDetail is created.

I have to find which user made database changes. If a user updates/deletes an account, it counts as top update/delete so I ignore AccountLevel, and AccountDetail. If an AccountLevel is updated/deleted, I ignore AccountDetail changes count. If there are AccountDetail updates/deletes but no AccountLevel, then I count AccountDetail updates/deletes. I wrote some but I think I'm going in circles.

[image: Data structure]

- Table 1: Account
- Table 2: AccountLevel
- Table 3: AccountDetail

Let's just focus on delete for now.
I'm getting a count of all the deletes on AccountDetail table grouped by AccountLevel. If there were 15 delete actions on AccountDetail 
on AccountLevelId 98982, I report a count of 15. However, AccountLevelId: 98981 is deleted on AccountLevel table, I ignore delete counts on AuditDetail table and report AccountLevel deletion.

Any help is much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: please explain scenarios in a logical way, your screenshot doesn't specify which is which.

Comment: I just updated my question and provided some logical explanation. Thanks again.